# How can I pass either model value as parameter or model from view to Javascript and then pass to controller method

Tags: json, asp.net-core, datatables

I am trying to pass model value ,  from view to javascript function and then from function to controller method. Is it possible to pass either model or model value as an argument to getall()

Model class

```
 public class VehicleReportVM
{
    public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; }
    public string ReportType { get; set; }
    public string ReportTitle { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Vehicles> VehicleList { get; set; }
}
```

view file  and java script file

```js
var dataTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();
});
function loadDataTable() {
    var dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Vehicle/GetAll",
        },
```

```html
@model Vehicle.Models.ViewModels.VehicleReportVM


@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/js/VehicleReport.js"></script>
}
```

Controller

```
public IActionResult GetAll(VehicleReportVM _model)
    {
        var allObj = _unitOfWork.VehicleRepo.GetAll(v=>v.IsDeleted==false,includeProperties: "VehicleStatus,VehicleType");
        return Json(new { data = allObj });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try that:

```
var myData = { ReportType: "x", ReportTitle: "y" };
function loadDataTable() {
    var dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Vehicle/GetAll",
            "data": myData
        },
        ...
```

or you can get the JSON data with jQuery GET or POST and then use it in DataTables:

```
var url =  "/Vehicle/GetAll";
var myData = { ReportType: "x", ReportTitle: "y" };
jQuery.post(url,myData,success,dataType);
```

and in the "*success*" you can call "*loadDataTable(jsonData)*"

```
function loadDataTable(jsonData) {
    var dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
        "data": jsonData
...
```